# "docker-compose up" results in "stat main.go: no such file or directory" error

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I'm new to `docker-compose` and `go` so be kind. I've looked at similar questions to this on SO, but they're either 1) for different versions of Go or 2) for Linux. I'm on Windows 10. Go version is `1.19`

I'm trying to follow along with a course which is out of date of course, and they're using a Mac, so that might be another reason why this isn't working, but I have a project structure and files that look like this (highlighted areas of interest):

[image: currentEnv]

When I try to run the command `docker-compose up` like it says in the course, I get the error. What's causing it and how do I fix it (as a newbie asking)?

Comment: I think you forgot to build, try this ```docker-compose up --build```

Comment: @bogdanoff Thanks, I tried that but still same error :(

Comment: willson I think I got it, your volume mount is overriding your project directory inside docker. either change or  remove volumes in docker compose . it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this where you build first and then try to run the binary. [here is the docker documentation on it](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/)

and in case the link breaks:

```
FROM golang:1.16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . ./

RUN go build -o /<your binary name>

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/<same binary name>" ]
```

Comment: Thanks! @bogdanoff pointed out that my `volumes` mount was overriding the project directory inside my `docker-compose.yaml` file, so I just commented out that `volumes` section and it worked. The guy doing the course must have already built this `app` ahead of time or something and just didn't tell us newbies about it :')

Comment: oh man good catch! and welcome to go!