# Go app (in docker container) not reflecting changes on page?

Tags: go, docker-compose

I'm new to Go, but having an annoying issue where changes in the code are not reflected on the page, unless I do another `--build` when I bring `up` the container. Is this normal? I'm running`Windows 10, Go 1.19, AMD, Docker Desktop/Compose.

If I change `"Hello, World!"` to some other string, CTRL+C the running app, and then run `docker-compose up`, the changes are NOT reflected on the page, even after clearing browser cache and using an incognito window. HOWEVER, if I run `docker-compose up --build`, the changes WILL be reflected.

Reminder I'm new to Go, but is this normal behaviour? Do I have to re-build the project in `docker-compose` each time to see the changes? Or do you see anything "off" in my code? I'm following a few year old Udemy course, so of course every step there's a new "thing" to troubleshoot as it doesn't work as shown *eye roll*

They suggest using `Air` for hot-reloading, which I'm also having an issue with as IT'S not working either, however I've opened a GitHub issue for that.

Here is the code from the various files:

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "ambassador/src/database"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func main() {

    // Connect to the database
    database.Connect()

    // Migrate tables in the database
    database.AutoMigrate()

    // Create a new fiber app, which is based on Express.js
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendString("Hello, World!")
    })

    app.Listen(":3000")
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.19

WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

# Use air for live go hot-reloading
# This one doesn't work, use go install instead
# RUN curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmtrek/air/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin

# Air does not work for me. Opening github issue. Skip for now
# RUN go install github.com/cosmtrek/air@latest
# CMD ["air"]

CMD ["go", "run", "main.go"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    backend:
        build: .
        ports:
            - 8000:3000
        # volumes:
        #   - .:/app
        depends_on:
            - db

    db:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ambassador
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        volumes:
            - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 33066:3306
```

**src > database > db.go**

```
package database

import (
    "ambassador/src/models"

    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var DB *gorm.DB

func Connect() {
    var err error
    DB, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open("root:root@tcp(db:3306)/ambassador"), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic("Could not connect with the database!")
    }
}

func AutoMigrate() {
    DB.AutoMigrate(models.User{})
}
```

**src > models > user.go**

```
package models

type User struct {
    Id           uint
    FirstName    string
    LastName     string
    Email        string
    Password     string
    IsAmbassador bool
}
```

**go.mod**

```
module ambassador

go 1.19

require github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2 v2.36.0

require (
    github.com/andybalholm/brotli v1.0.4 // indirect
    github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.6.0 // indirect
    github.com/jinzhu/inflection v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/jinzhu/now v1.1.5 // indirect
    github.com/klauspost/compress v1.15.0 // indirect
    github.com/valyala/bytebufferpool v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/valyala/fasthttp v1.38.0 // indirect
    github.com/valyala/tcplisten v1.0.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220227234510-4e6760a101f9 // indirect
    gorm.io/driver/mysql v1.3.5 // indirect
    gorm.io/gorm v1.23.8 // indirect
)
```

The same code is included in [this screenshot of my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Xta.png).

Comment: You seem to have included an image file in place of your code.  It seems like there's a lot going on there, the text is rather small, and you've chosen low-contrast colors; above all else, I can't copy the text out of this image to try to reproduce the issue or find it later.  Can you [edit] the question to remove the image and include the actual code instead?

Comment: You can click the image to make it bigger. All the details are in there and it's much cleaner than a bunch of code blocks, but I will update the question to include the code...

Answer (score 3):

Go isn’t a script language and needs in rebuild and restart application to apply changes

You can use Golang fresh for rebuild and restart your app

https://github.com/gravityblast/fresh

Add this to your Dockerfile

```
RUN go install github.com/pilu/fresh@latest
...
CMD [ "fresh" ]
```

Comment: So to answer my original question, you DO need to `--build` everytime you make a change to a page? I know that using a third-party package will do this for you, but seems odd that the entire app needs to be re-built before a front end change is made? But I guess that's just Go?

Comment: It's a compiled language, and even without Docker, you'd normally need to `go build` your application on every change.  In a Docker context, a Docker image is normally an immutable copy of your application: you can't update the code or assets in an image, you always build a new image.  You don't have to use Docker in your core development flow even if you're eventually going to use it for deployment.

Comment: Ugh, thanks for this, however fresh is also not "working" for me either. It's doing the same thing as my issue that I opened on Air's GitHub page. It downloads, and runs, but it doesn't actively update/rebuild after any saving. It just sits there saying it's "watching" but it's not? Any ideas? The commented out volumes section maybe?

Comment: ...or maybe because it's in a docker container? This Udemy course I'm following is proving to be quite the challenge...

Comment: I think you should create volume from your code dir to the code dir inside container

Answer (score 1):

You are not mounting any files into your container, only copying them once on image build. This is why you are not seeing anychanges unless you build, or copy new files into the container.

You've already commented out a volume from your docker-compose.yaml, but if you uncomment those lines you should see that changes are reflected without rebuilding.

Comment: It's interesting, because I commented that volumes section out because of my last issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73257031/docker-compose-up-results-in-stat-main-go-no-such-file-or-directory-error/73257186?noredirect=1#comment129376683_73257186

Comment: The course I'm following said to make that volumes value `app` but I think it needs to be `go-ambassador` to match my project tree structure. I've changed it to that and it works. Thanks! And thanks for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question — NO, you DO NOT need to add the `--build` tag when running up your docker-compose file. It doesn't relate to Go, it relates only to docker containers working logic.

If we come to the live-reload problem then the problem is with the technology docker uses for file sharing between a host system and containers.

I have had the same issues on mac when tried to use not the Docker Desktop but an alternative like Rancher which even uses docker CLI via [moby](https://mobyproject.org). When I switched back to the original Docker Desktop which uses gRPC FUSE, osxfs, and VirtioFS — with all of them worked like a charm.

I don't know how this feature is implemented on windows, but I'm sure you could dig into this direction.